# StructureMap fails on IIS 7.5 with AppPoolIdentity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, iis-7.5

I have a problem with ASP.NET MVC application hosted on IIS 7.5 on separate application pool, configured with AppPoolIdentity and .NET 4.0 Framework.

The application is **working normally for some time and suddenly part of controllers start to throw an exception** inside StructureMap:

> `System.ArgumentNullException`: Trying
>   to find an Instance of type [`MyType`]
>   Parameter name: `instance`
>
> in
>   `StructureMap.InstanceCache.Get(Type
>   pluginType, Instance instance) +376`

The type requested was registered correctly (and was resolved properly just a minute before the exception occured). I can't verify it is still registered, as **`WhatDoIHave` throws an exception, too**:

> `NullReferenceException`: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. in
>   `StructureMap.Diagnostics.WhatDoIHaveWriter.writeInstance(InstanceRef
>   instance) +133`

Looks like StructureMap's **internal cache gets corrupted** somehow.

**The problem disappears** when I change AppPoolIdentity to "real" local system user credentials. So it looks like the problem is somewhere between IIS and StructureMap. Maybe app pool recycling makes problems here? But it is configured to recycle every 1740 minutes and it fails sometimes after 5 minutes from its start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem appeared to be very different, I don't know how it may looked like connected to app pools and privileges.

The flaw is in `GetNamedInstance<T>` StructureMap's container method. I requesting a named instance, which is not registered, StructureMap tries to create the instance and add it to the container. Creation fails, but nevertheless, StructureMap registers `null` in the container. Each subsequent request for that named instance fails when encounter this `null`.

Our workaround is that we use `GetAllInstances<T>` instead of `GetNamedInstance<T>` and iterate manually through all instances of `T` to find matching one.